# Searching a large list of strings for a set of strings that may or may not be present

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've looked up similar questions but the answers there don't quite fit my situation, which I think is more simplified.

I have a custom application that can export an .xlsx file listing feature codes for features that exist in a developing product.  The feature codes are all single-word blocks of test, such as:
FeatureRed
FeatureYellow
ThingOne
ThingTwo (etc.)

They all appear in a column (G) and a typical export has perhaps 100 to 200 features in it.
Each feature code is in its own row cell.  They are not in any particularly knowable order.
Let's call this list "ProductFeatureList".

I have a separate static list of features, which we'll call "MyFeatures", where I want to know which of MyFeatures are in ProductFeatureList.  MyFeatures is presently only around 20 items, but that could grow in the future.  MyFeatures as a set may or may not intersect with the set of ProductFeatureList.

The format of the features in MyFeatures is the same as ProductFeatureList.  For example, MyFeatures might contain:
FeatureBlue
FeatureYellow
ThingTwo
ThingExtra (etc.)

In the above example, I want to extract that FeatureYellow and ThingTwo were found in ProductFeatureList.

There will be items in MyFeatures that are not found in ProductFeatureList.
There will be lots of items in ProductFeatureList that I'm not looking for (which are not on MyFeatures)

Ideally, I'd like my output to be a list of the hits, in another column (say, column K). I would like to be able to order that list eventually, perhaps alphabetically.

I suspect this can be done in a formula that scans the list of words in MyFeatures against each cell in Row G of ProductFeatures, but I don't know how to do this to collect the hits and write them to another column.  Copying the feature name from a hit in column G to another column cell is ideal.

I need to perform this search against many different ProductFeatureList files each day, so leveraging Excel to handle this will save a lot of time.

Comment: Try to use `COUNTIF` function.